# Change Facebook Login button from Logout to Login?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

After user logins via facebook, the button will change from "Login" to "Logout", is there any way pro grammatically change back to "Login" status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be logged out to show `LoginButton` again, otherwise you can't see `LoginButton`. If you want to logout pro grammatically, you can do it like,

```
public void logOut() {
    loginButton.performClick();
}
```

and call this method where you want to show `LoginButton` again.

Answer (score 0):

when you login to facebook using facebook login button it change to logout automatically, if you try to change logout to login the login status of your app will change,
so i recommend you to use custom button for facebook login